Error al correr el comando npm run serve en vue/cli
En un trabajo para un curso, estoy instalando vue/cli y al terminar y correr el comando npm run serve me tira un error.
Los pasos para la instalación son los siguientes:
npm install -g @vue/cli
vue create (nombre de carpeta)

Seleccioné las siguientes características
Vue CLI v5.0.8
? Please pick a preset: Manually select features
? Check the features needed for your project: Babel, Vuex
? Choose a version of Vue.js that you want to start the project with 3.x
? Where do you prefer placing config for Babel, ESLint, etc.? In dedicated config files
? Save this as a preset for future projects? No

Ejecuté los comandos para abrir el servidor:
cd crud
npm run serve

y me muestra el siguiente error:
Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename index.html
 
ERROR in Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename index.html
    
webpack compiled with 1 error


Hola, seguí tus instrucciones (+1 por compartirlas) utilizando nodejs v22.1.0 en una terminal bash (Linux), pero no pude replicar el error. ¿Podrías compartir tus archivos de configuración de Vue, jsconf, babel y package.json? Esto podría ayudarnos a identificar el problema. Puedes echar un vistazo a este enlace  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42148632/conflict-multiple-assets-emit-to-the-same-filename
